# Image not resizing after orientation

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, orientation

My image is resizing wrong when in landscape. I am creating a connect 4 application and have an image repeated of empty cells for the board.

When orientation is portrait it looks like this,

[image: http://puu.sh/6Sdw9.jpg]

However when it orientation is changed to landscape,

[image: http://puu.sh/6SdyN.jpg]

I created an image of of the empty cell, this is the XML for layout,

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/r6c4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/arrow4"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:contentDescription="@string/emptyBox"
android:src="@drawable/empty"
android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Is there anything else I would need to provide?

Is there any issues with my XML?

I have tried changing the width and height to match_parent but I get this,

[image: https://puu.sh/6ShwO.jpg]

Is there a way of grouping all the images of the empty cells and resizing them all to fit landscape screen?

Thanks

Comment: So would you must like to use this in landscape+portrait orientation or Is it okay if you only show in portrait mode even someone try to change the orientation of devie?

Comment: Sagar - I did think about this. However would this be against androids design principles?

Comment: Not at all. If you want to run your app in portrait mode only then Its perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing **android:layout_width** and **android:layout_height** to **"match_parent"** may fix the issue.  That will make it so the image fills the container it is in.  "wrap_content" means it will use as little room as possible, which is why it is resizing strangely when the screen it put into landscape mode.  Instead of filling the new space it tries to use the same amount of space as in portrait orientation.

See the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for a more detailed look at the differences between the two.

Comment: It did not work. It looks like this http://puu.sh/6Shkw.jpg 

I think it is matching the individual images, is there a way to put it as one whole image, or other ways around this?